# Python OOP Monty Hall not giving the expected results

Tags: python

Trying out some OOP in python, I tried to create a Monty Hall Problem simulation that is giving odd results.  I implement three different strategies that a player can choose from, either to stay with the first door selected, switch to the second closed door, or randomly choose between them.

```
import random

class Door():
  behind    = None
  is_open   = False
  is_chosen = False
  def __init__(self,name=None):
    self.name = name
  def open(self):
    self.is_open = True
  def choose(self):
    self.is_chosen = True

class Goat():
  is_a = 'goat'

class Car():
  is_a = 'car'

class Player():
  door = None
  def choose(self,door):
    self.door = door
    self.door.choose()
  def open(self):
    self.door.open()
    if self.door.behind.is_a == 'car':
      return True
    return False


def play(strategy):
  player = Player()
  items = [Goat(),Goat(),Car()]
  doors = [Door(name='a'),Door(name='b'),Door(name='c')]
  for door in doors:
    item = items.pop()
    door.behind = item
  random.shuffle(doors)
  player.choose(random.choice(doors))
  if strategy == 'random':
    if random.choice([True,False]):
      for door in doors:
        if not door.is_open and not door.is_chosen:
          final = door
          break
    else:
      final = player.door
  elif strategy == 'switch':
    for door in doors:
      if not door.is_open and not door.is_chosen:
        final = door
        break
  elif strategy == 'stay':
    final = player.door
  player.choose(final)
  if player.open():
    return True
  else:
    return False


## Play some games
for strategy in ['random','switch','stay']:
  results = []
  for game in range(0,10000):
    if play(strategy):
      results.append(True)
    else:
      results.append(False)

  ## Gather the results
  wins  = 0
  loses = 0
  for game in results:
    if game:
      wins += 1
    else:
      loses += 1
  print 'results:\tstrategy={}\twins={}\tloses={}'.format(strategy,str(wins),str(loses))
```

But every time I run it, I get something like:

```
results:        strategy=random wins=3369       loses=6631
results:        strategy=switch wins=3369       loses=6631
results:        strategy=stay   wins=3320       loses=6680
```

Why is this giving nearly the same results for each strategy?  Shouldn't the 'switch' strategy give a ratio of ~66% wins and 'stay' give ~33%?

Comment: BTW, it doesn't make much difference for this program, but it's recommended in Python 2 to have your classes inherit from `object`, eg `class Door(object)` so that you get new-style classes rather than old-style (old-style classes do not exist in Python 3). Also, why bother making special Goat and Car classes? You might as well just use "Goat" and "Car" string objects. It'd be more efficient, since the interpreter knows that strings are immutable, so it can "recycle" the same string object when it detects duplicate string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not playing the game correctly.  After the contestant chooses a door, the host reveals a goat behind one of the other two doors, and then offers the contestant the opportunity to switch -- you're allowing a choice between three doors instead of two.  Here's a revised `play()` function:

```
def play(strategy):
    player = Player()
    items = [Goat(), Goat(), Car()]
    doors = [Door(name='a'), Door(name='b'), Door(name='c')]

    random.shuffle(items)

    for door in doors:
        item = items.pop()
        door.behind = item

    player.choose(random.choice(doors))

    # player has chosen a door, now show a goat behind one of the other two

    show = None
    for door in doors:
        if not (door.is_open or door.is_chosen) and door.behind.is_a == 'goat':
            show = door
            show.open()
            break

    # The player has now been shown a goat behind one of the two doors not chosen

    if strategy == 'random':
        if random.choice([True, False]):
            for door in doors:
                if not (door.is_open or door.is_chosen):
                    final = door
                    break
        else:
            final = player.door

    elif strategy == 'switch':
        for door in doors:
            if not (door.is_open or door.is_chosen):
                final = door
                break

    elif strategy == 'stay':
        final = player.door

    player.choose(final)

    return player.open()
```

That produces results like:

```
results:    strategy=random wins=4977   loses=5023
results:    strategy=switch wins=6592   loses=3408
results:    strategy=stay   wins=3368   loses=6632
```

Comment: D'oh!  I don't know how I didn't see that!  I'm slowly starting to get this OOP thing down...